# Python 3 - TCP Socket Connection - Unicode

Tags: python, sockets, unicode

I have started studying socket programming in Python 3.

I have came across some scripts that send Unicode to a listening socket.

An example of one script I found, which was used to turn relays on and off had

```
TCP_IP = '192.168.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 500
BUFFER_SIZE = 80
MESSAGE = '\x21\x01\x00'
```

The variable MESSAGE was sent to the target system using:

```
s.send(MESSAGE)
```

When I looked at this in the Python shell, the message translated to:

```
'!\x01\x00'
```

Obviously the code required by the receiving machine to tell it to make a change on the relays state.

So I wanted to ask:

a) Can Unicode be sent to any listening port on a system and a response received?
b) Can Unicode be used on a computer to lock the screen 'Ctrl+Alt+Del'?
c) Are there any tutorials, books etc that could help with this?

I have created a listening socket in Python 3 and sent code from another Python script on another computer and got a response but with using Python for both client and server then it will encode and decode as instructed.

The reason I ask is I see the use of Unicode such as the example above in many different scripts and I am just interested in learning more on this area.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Unicode is not magic, it is just a character encoding. What gets sent over the network are bytes, and in python you can convert between character strings and bytes using the `str.encode()` method and the bytes string constructor.

Comment: Could you please clarify your questions? a) you can send whatever you want over a socket, it's all binary, the only question is whether or not the server would understand. b) I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I havent thought my question through well enough. I thought unicode could be used in a way to send an actual command to a computer. For example being able to send a command using unicode to open the command prompt window. Looks like im looking at it the wrong way but thanks for coming back to me on this anyway.

Comment: Shellcode!!! It was shellcode I kept seeing on programs. Kinda big subject but I know what im looking for now.